# Change "src" attribute to "data-src" inside WordPress images on Widgets

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using the following PHP code to change the **"src"** attribute

The code changes **"src"** to **"data-src"**

and ads a new value to **"src"**

**THE PROBLEM** is that this does not work on images within **WIDGETS**

**ONLY WORKS** for images within content like post or pages.

**QUESTION:** Can anyone help me to make this work on images within widgets too?

```
/* CHANGE IMAGES ATTRIBUTES */

add_filter('the_content', 'filter');
function filter($content) {
    return str_replace('<img src="', '<img data-src="', $content);
}

add_filter('the_content','new_content');
function new_content($content) {
    $content = str_replace('<img','<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7"', $content);
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: You might get more results searching on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/